Properties of matrices with a multiplicative order
I have been trying to find any article or sources talking about the structure and properties of matrices with a multiplicativw order, i.e.
a matrix $A$ has a multiplicative order of $n$ if and only if $A^n = I$ and that there does not exist a number smaller than n that fullfills the previous condition. Note that I'm only interested in values where is is a natural number. But I've come up ghastly short. For clarification, the matrices I'm studying are non-singular complex matrices; so any part woulf help.
Any suggestions for sources or refferences?

It's easy enough to characterize these matrices, that I doubt you will find a reference other than an exercise. Here are some steps:

The eigenvalues of $A$ satisfy $\lambda^n=1$, i.e. they are $n^{\rm th}$-roots of unity.

Let $J$ be the Jordan form of $A$. You have $J^n=I$, and this implies that $J$ is diagonal. To see this, show that if $J_k$ is a non-diagonal Jordan block with eigenvalue $\omega$, the $1,2$ entry of $J_k^n$ is $n\omega^{n-1}$, which prevents it from being $I$.

So $J$ is diagonal, with $J_{kk}$ an $n^{\rm th}$-root of unity. At least one of these has to be primitive, since $A^m\ne I$ for $m<n$.

Hence $A=SDS^{-1}$, where $S$ is non-singulat and $D$ is diagonal, with $D_{kk}$ an $n^{\rm th}$-root of unity. At least one of these has to be primitive.


